# Notepad++ FTP plugin with Google Compute Engine

Tags: linux, ftp, notepad++, google-compute-engine

I've been using the Google Compute Engine since the day I heard it came out--I've been primarily using a micro instance to hone my HTML/CSS/PHP skills, while I learn them at Codecademy. My problem is that editing the HTML &c files in nano via the terminal can get frustrating, and is definitely slower than using a GUI-based word processor.

When I did coding on Windows, I primarily relied on Notepad++, and I just recently learned about the FTP plugin. I have Notepad++ installed on my computer (Ubuntu 13.10, via PlayOnLinux/WINE) and have had no trouble with it...except with using the FTP plugin to my GCE instance.

I've configured the plugin properly (as far as I can tell):

```
Hostname -- <mydomain>.com
Connection type -- FTP
Port -- 21
Username -- <myusername>
Password --
```

...and then on the Authentication tab I have it set to use private key file authentication, and point to the appropriate private key, as well as the passphrase I set for it. (NB: I have set a firewall rule to allow TCP on port 21 to 0.0.0.0)

I get the following in the console when I try to connect:

```
-> TYPE I  
Connecting
-> Quit  
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

Is there anything I need to do, or is it even possible to set up NPPFTP with GCE this way?

Answer (score 1):

[NPPFTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/) supports SCP and SFTP. FTP is generally insecure and tricky to configure firewall rules for. Have you tried SCP / SFTP instead?

Make sure that you are using the same SSH key that Google Compute Engine uses. On Mac OSX and other Unices, it is usually located at `$HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine`.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that if you've used puttyGen to generate your keys, then you will need to export the key as an OpenSSH Key.